# Ember passing a model to transitionToRoute

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-router, ember-controllers

I'm using Ember-cli with ember 1.11

I'm trying to use the transitionToRoute method in a controller to transition to a route and feed it a dynamically generated object as the model.

Here's my controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {      
      launch_scanner: function(){
        console.log('launch_scanner');
        var model = {name: "Edward", phone: "123", email: "email@test.com"};
        //the final app will pull the model variable from a QR scanner

        this.transitionToRoute('addcontact', model);
     }
  }      
});
```

When I trigger this action, the transitionToRoute method causes this error:

> Uncaught Error: More context objects were passed than there are
>   dynamic segments for the route: addcontact

If I leave out the model parameter, it transitions to the addcontact route just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my router file:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', {path: '/'});
  this.resource('addcontact', {path: '/addcontact'});
});

export default Router;
```

Comment: Show your router file, please, to see what parameters you need to pass

Comment: I've updated to show the router file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with a classic problem occurring in many Ember applications which is how to handle "new"/"create" situations.

You cannot define a route such as

```
this.route('addcontact', { path: /addcontact/:thing_id }
```

because the the new contact doesn't have an id, and won't until it is persisted to the server, at which point it won't be new any more.

Yet there is some point in your application, in your case I suppose on the "home" page, where the user pressed a "New Contact" button, and it may have useful information about what to create or how to create it, and might even want to create the object right there using `this.store.createRecord`--yet how does one pass that information, or the new record, to the `addcontacdt` route, which can have no dynamic segment?

Some ideas include:

1. Create the new contact in your `home` route or whatever, and store it in the controller. Then, in the `model` hook of the new route, retrieve it using `this.controllerFor('home').get('newContact')`.
2. Pass necessary parameters for creating the new object, if any, to the `addcontact` route as **query parameters**, using `transitionTo('newcontact', queryParameters)`. Then, in the `model` hook, create the new object using `this.store.createRecord('contact', transition.queryParameters)` or something equivalent.

Comment: I discovered that I could define my route as:

this.resource('addcontact', {path: '/addcontact/:info'});

and this allowed me to pass the new object as a model through the transitionToRoute method. I don't know if this is proper, because I couldn't really find anything in the docs about it, but it worked.

Comment: Is it possible to pass without query parameters?

Answer (score 0):

That's normal, because you don't have any dynamic segment in your addContact route. You should change your router to

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', {path: '/'});
  this.resource('addcontact', {path: '/addcontact/:id'});
});
```

Now you could pass the model Id instead of the whole model to trigger the `model` hook. Alternatively you can pass the whole model, but it will not trigger the `model` hook. Although you can still modify your model in the `afterModel` hook.

Comment: Well, since the data will be generated on the fly, it would not have an id yet, so how would I just pass the whole model through?

Comment: You don't need to change your Controller code, just your router. It should work. Have a look at the ember doc if you are unsure: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_transitionToRoute

Comment: @EdwardEllsworth Please don't forget to accept a solution so future users can know what works :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate to a Subroute for an unsaved Record you have 2 Options

Either save your model before transitioning to the route

```
model.save().then(function(result){
   self.transitionToRoute('route',result.id)
});
```

or generate an id for the model in createRecord if you don't want to save the model (maybe the user can cancel and you don't want to handle the delete)

A basic function for id creating with low potential of identical ids would be:

```
generateIdForRecord: function() {
    var d = new Date().getTime();
    var uuid = 'xxxxyyyxxxxxxxxyyxyxxxyyy'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c){
        var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
        d = Math.floor(d / 16);
        return (c === 'x' ? r : (r & 0x7 | 0x8)).toString(16);
    });
    return uuid;
}
```

Using this approach a not yet saved model has an id to transition to, just think about handling the transitions from that route since the current id is no longer valid after saving the model (model gets real id from server in response).